# .tan files on my Kindle

Tags: kindle

How do I read/interpret the .tan files in the documents directory of 
my Kindle? I believe they hold my bookmarks/etc, but in what format?

Google was not helpful here.

EDIT: Thanks to everyone who helped. Although I didn't find an answer, it turns out "My Clippings.txt" has everything I need. Wish I'd seen that earlier!

Comment: Have you tried opening them in a text editor? (I don't have a Kindle to try it myself.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some info about it was documented here: http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/AZW

HTH